# Android Background Size for Tablet?

Tags: android, wallpaper

i was searching and cant find a solution, because its the first time I am working with android. So whats are the working dimensions for background images for android tablets 
(with lollipop). Should it be bigger than 1920x1080 because of the parallax effect on paging?

Comment: Check : http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For tablet resolutions below link will surely help you.

Nicely written blog :

http://thedigitaldisciple.net/tablet-screen-resolution-chart/

http://i1.wp.com/thedigitaldisciple.net/wp-content/uploads/Screen-Master-8-2014.jpg

In above image, check **PPI, Pix H & Pix W** columns

Official document :

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Thank you for this... so the backgrounds got the same dimensions as the display and get scaled for the parallax-effect?

Comment: Yes, for parallax effect your background will not change. Above background your parallax view will come. Mark this answer useful if its helping to you.